# Updating nested_attribute on a model, doesn't update the has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model relationship:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions_roles, inverse_of: :role, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :permissions, through: :permissions_roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions_roles, allow_destroy: true
end

class PermissionsRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :permission
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Permission class has `id`, `name` etc.

I am using Rails 4.2.4 and facing an error with update method of the role model. When I update the nested attribute `permissions_roles`, it doesn't update the has_many :through `permissions` attribute of the model. This is what I did to verify the error in rails console:

```
> role = Role.create(name: 'role', permissions_roles_attributes: [{permission_id: 1}])

# Checking permissions for the role
> role.permissions
[#<Permission:0x007ff3c3963160
id: 1,
name: "read">]

# Updating the nested attributes
> role.update(permissions_roles_attributes: [{permission_id: 10}])

# Checking nested attributed - Return as expected
> role.permissions_roles
=> [#<PermissionsRole:0x007ff3bbade740 id: 78, permission_id: 1, role_id: 11>, #<PermissionsRole:0x007ff3bc8fdee8 id: 79, permission_id: 10, role_id: 11>]

# Checking has_many through relationship. Stale :(
> role.permissions
=> [#<Permission:0x007ff3be1d29f0
id: 1,
name: "read">]
```

I have to manually call `reload` on the model or `role.permissions` attribute to make sure `role.permissions` is updated. Is there any way for `permissions` attribute to automatically update whenever I update `permissions_roles` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to specify the id of the `PermissionRole` model, which you want to update:

```
role.update(permissions_roles_attributes: [{ id: 78, permission_id: 10}])
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply. I don't want to update the `permissions_roles`. It is anyway updated. What i meant was that when I update the `permissions_roles` of roles, the has_many through relationship, `permissions` isn't updated. I have to reload the whole model to refresh the `permissions` attribute